# Protractor - works well on localhost but remote throws Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

When I execute `protractor protractor.conf.js --baseUrl=http://localhost:4200/`, it works well - fills data, validates elements, etc.

When I try to test exactly the same website via remote URL `protractor protractor.conf.js --baseUrl=http://the-same-website.com/`, it opens up in browser, logins and all necessary parts are loaded like in localhost but Protractor/Jasmine does not fill/click/validate anything and I get timeout after specified time:

```
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
      at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
      at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
      at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  - Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds
    (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
```

There are other threads will similar problems on Stack Overflow - tried `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`  and `Protractor.waitForAngular(false)` but then page doesn't load properly and tests fail because elements aren't found.

**UPDATE 1**

The test below works well on localhost - outputs success or failure depending on h1 but on remote URL it doesn't check anything despite web is loaded:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

describe('example-test', () => {

  const PATH_TO_TEST = 'specific-path/to/test';

  beforeEach(() => {
    browser.get(PATH_TO_TEST);
  });

  it('should exist header', () => {
    expect(element(by.css('h1')).getText()).toEqual('test');
  });
});
```

If I add logging, I see output but `expect` is not executed:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

describe('example-test', () => {

  const PATH_TO_TEST = 'specific-path/to/test';

  beforeEach(() => {
    browser.get(PATH_TO_TEST);
    console.log('beforeEach');
  });

  it('should exist header', () => {
    expect(element(by.css('h1')).getText()).toEqual('test');
    console.log('test end');
  });
});
```

Protractor config:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I add `browser.sleep` and `browser.ignoreSynchronization`, tests begin to work but then I need to add `browser.sleep` for every synchronization which doesn't look nice:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  browser.get('path/to/test');
  browser.sleep(3000);
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
});
```

**It seems that Protractor does not recognize page as fully loaded or as Angular web.**

Why Protractor does not validate content despite the page is loaded properly?

Comment: Are you testing an angular site? Are you creating any async functions in your test? Do you have SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false in your config?

Comment: It's Angular site. Tests just do browser.ger in beforeEach and standard functions like expect, click, etc. so no explicit async functions.

Comment: I don't use SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER property.

Comment: can you try increasing the 30 second jasmine wait in your conf to 120 seconds just to see if it still fails. Need to change this line defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000

Comment: Increased, still fails - page is loaded but nothing is clicked or validated.

Comment: Just to confirm is it still failing with Jasmine Async timeout issue?

Comment: Yes, the same error.

Comment: Updated with possible workaround which allows to run tests.

Comment: Does your application have a third party or non-angular login page by any chance?

Comment: Yes, it does automatic login.

Comment: Updated my original answer. Check it out and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186808/discussion-between-dublindev-and-justas).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: Completed changed original proposed answer.

This issue could be due to the nature of your login page. If your login is non-angular then you must instruct protractor not to wait for angular to become testable (which it will by default). To do this you can use the **browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)** command which it the recommended new way as opposed to the previous **browser.ignoreSynchronization = true**.

After you have logged into your application you can set your **browser.waitForAngularEnabled** back to true and the rest of your tests in that spec should behave correctly.

```
describe('Main', function {
  beforeAll(function () {
      browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
      Site.login();
      //after you have successfully logged into you site you can 
      browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
  });

  it('should show the main page', function () {
     //Your code
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't do explicit login, it is done automatically in Angular app. You've mixed true and false - it should be browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); after browser.get. I need browser.sleep to wait for page load.

Comment: In the case of a non-angular login page, which I mistakenly assumed you were using, you do need to set waitForAngularEnabled(false) before you navigate to the page. This way protractor knows not to attempt to look for the angular testability property to settle before it attempts to interact with page. Despite it replacing ignoreSynchronization the results of setting it to true and false have the opposite effects.