# Browser URL does not loading when Protractor test runs remotely

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor

I am trying to run my Protractor test on a remote server (selenium grid). I have Jenkin job to execute commands. When I run the exact test on my local server, the browser (both Firefox and Chrome works) get starts and load the URL and complete the tests. But when I execute via Jenkins it starts the browser but does not load the URLs. After some time Jenkins job gets timed out but still, browsers are open and do nothing. any idea? help much appreciated

I am passing the remote server as follows in my config.js,

`seleniumAddress:http://citest-grid.com:4444/wd/hub`

Comment: Please share the Jenkin Code with us where you are loading URL

Comment: Double check the webdriver binary is compatible with the browser on the node of selenium grid.  And confirm you explicitly specify the downloaded webdriver binary path in register cmd as following.  `java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/eclipse/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -port 5556 -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome, version=ANY, maxInstances=10, platform=ANY"`  More detail: https://developers.perfectomobile.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21435360

Comment: @akshaypatil, I have 3 stages, 

1. check out the branch 
2. npm install
3  the cmd I am running to start the test is 

```
npm run e2e -- --tags=@api 
```

Comment: @yong  I did exactly what you suggested, but same issue

Comment: I have similar problem too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204420/protractor-works-well-on-localhost-but-remote-throws-timeout-async-callback

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue removing 'disable-infobars' in the chromeOptions. But not sure why

`'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['disable-infobars']
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below code

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    directConnect: true //Hope by adding this your problem gets resolved
  }
```

Remove `seleniumAddress` from your config.

Comment: if I remove the seleniumAddress then it's talking to localhost right?
directConnect: true is working for local , Thx

Comment: but if I add  directConnect: true and run remotely again same results and getting following error 

````[chrome #01-0] [21:51:14] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[chrome #01-0] 
[chrome #01-0] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test-ui-auto-qa/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546
[chrome #01-0]         throw new ctor(message);
[chrome #01-0]               ^
[chrome #01-0] WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally````

Comment: @user8267843 refer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558077/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-driver-info-chromedri>